# How do I log into user with ldap_bind based off of uid?

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

Right now I have to write the full query, to be able to log into a user.
Is there a way to do an ldap_bind with just the unique identifier versus writing the full rdn.

Or if I could specify the base DC, so that way if there are sub-ou's with users in it, it will be able to check.

```
ldap_bind($ds, "uid=my_user", "password") versus  

ldap_bind($ds,"uid=my_user,ou=developers,dc=mycompan,dc=org","password")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the full DN to authenticate against LDAP. No other way.

What you might be able to do is do a search for an LDAP-entry containing your prefered login-data using a default user account or an anonymous bind. Then retrieve the DN from the returned entry and use that for a second bind. That way your user only has to enter the unique identifier and you are still able to do the bind using a DN.

For a code example have a look at https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592